# Postgres TextSearch not filtering Distinct entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, text-search

We are trying weed out duplicates on specific column using a Text query.

Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT 
    distinct on (title) title", 
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title), query, 1) AS rank 
FROM  
    products, 
    to_tsquery('english',''english','Ribeye | Starter | Cheese | Assortment'') query 
WHERE 
    query @@ to_tsvector(title) AND 
    book_id = '37' as result 
ORDER BY 
    rank DESC limit 10 offset 0
```

For some reason we are still receiving occasional duplicate titles when using TEXT Searches.

Results in:

```
"Ribeye Starter Cheese Assortment" 
"Filet Mignon Starter Cheese Assortment" 
"Ambassadors Assortment" 
"Ambassadors Assortment" 
"Strip Steak Starter Cheese Assortment"
"After Dinner Cheese  Assortment"
"Ambassadors Assortment"
"Chairmans Assortment"
```

Using the distinct without TSVectors works fine but introducing Text Searches Ignores the PostGres Distinct Keyword.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have psql in front of me to test... but this line from the docs caught my eye:

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

So just add the "title" to the `ORDER`:

```
... ORDER BY title,rank DESC ...
```